# Find a subset of columns of a data frame that have some missing values

Tags: dataframe, julia, missing-data

Given the following data frame from DataFrames.jl:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(x1=[1, 2, 3], x2=Union{Int,Missing}[1, 2, 3], x3=[1, 2, missing])
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x1     x2      x3
     │ Int64  Int64?  Int64?
─────┼────────────────────────
   1 │     1       1        1
   2 │     2       2        2
   3 │     3       3  missing
```

I would like to find columns that contain `missing` value in them.

I have tried:

```
julia> names(df, Missing)
String[]
```

but this is incorrect as the `names` function, when passed a type, looks for subtypes of the passed type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to find columns that *actually* contain `missing` value use:

```
julia> names(df, any.(ismissing, eachcol(df)))
1-element Vector{String}:
 "x3"
```

In this approach we iterate each column of the `df` data frame and check if it contains at least one missing value.

If you want to find columns that *potentially* can contain missing value you need to check their element type:

```
julia> names(df, [eltype(col) >: Missing for col in eachcol(df)]) # using a comprehension
2-element Vector{String}:
 "x2"
 "x3"

julia> names(df, .>:(eltype.(eachcol(df)), Missing)) # using broadcasting
2-element Vector{String}:
 "x2"
 "x3"
```